# Live Kali Linux stuck at Dragon Logo on shut down or restart

Tags: kali-linux, shutdown

I made a live Kali USB drive using Rufus and Kali Live ISO (I am using Windows 11). When I boot using USB on my laptop, the OS although starts slowly but still boots up. But after I restart or shutdown, it does not shut down, and is stuck in the dragon logo, and I have to manually press hold the power button to power off.

### Things I have tried

- Used``kali-linux-2023.2-live-everything-amd64.iso`as well as`kali-linux-2023.2-live-amd64.iso`
- Made USB drive using ISO as well as DD format.
- Made Persistent storage using Rufus, as well as using [guide available in Kali Linux's website](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/).
- Booted Kali Linux in the normal mode, as well as in the Persistent Storage mode.
- Although gedit was not installled already. I updated using sudo apt-get update and installed gedit using apt-get gedit. And then used

  ```shell
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub/
  ```

  to delete `quiet-splash`, but the file opened was empty.
- Tried two pendrives, one with USB 2.0, and one with USB 3.1.
- I have checked the checksum as well with the website, and they match of the iso files.

All of these things did not change the outcome, and the boot time was also not much different between USB 2.0 and USB 3.1, but one time when I booted using USB 2.0 and Persistent Storage, the boot was very slow and step wise, like after the dragon logo disappeared and the `-` sign appeared and then when it disappeared, the top taskbar appeared, and then the desktop wallpaper and desktop files appeared. Every step took a solid, 5 min.

PS - The changes I made were not saved even when I booted using Persistent storage. Maybe because of the forced shut down.

Comment: Same issue, it seems to be an issue with the latest iso image. I am using a usb 3.1 drive on a 3.2 usb port so this is not the issue, it's just legitimately stuck. Also if anyone from Kali is coming by, it's impossible to register a new account on the bug tracker because the captcha system is down (both visual and audio). I guess the best is to try an older release meanwhile this issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

I retested the weekly unstable Kali live image release (W38 2023) because of wifi firmware issues, and the very slow or infinite shutdown issue reappeared. But I fixed it.

The TL;DR version is that if you hit F12 key at shutdown of Kali and see `systemd-shutdown: waiting for gst-plugin-scan` taking a looooong time, then the culprit is GStreamer, a multimedia player that you can simply replace with `vlc`, so you can simply uninstall it with `sudo apt remove gstreamer*` and your shutdown should become instant right away.

If you want the changes to persist, here are the steps, from the start when you just downloaded a [Kali live image](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-live):

1. First, burn your image using Rufus, disable persistence, click on Burn and it will ask whether you want to use the DD copy method (sector by sector) or files method, select DD copy method, otherwise Kali won't work, you will be stuck with a buggy grub boot.
2. Secondly, we need to make this usb drive persistent (so that we can modify the system to fix the shutdown). Boot into the Kali live image on your USB drive, then follow the [official instructions](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/).

To summarize, you are creating a 3rd partition on your USB drive to fill in the rest of the available space and that will store the persistent data. If you don't have time following the official instructions, here are the commands you have to run (yes modifying the very usb drive you are currently using to boot into Kali works fine):

```
lsblk # to list all partitions, including on USB drive
usb=/dev/sda # EDIT ME: replace with usb drive where there is Kali as shown by lsblk, the partitions should be mounted to `/something/live` 
sudo fdisk $usb <<< $(printf "n\np\n\n\n\nw")
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L persistence ${usb}3
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
sudo mount ${usb}3 /mnt/my_usb
echo "/ union" | sudo tee /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
sudo umount ${usb}3
```

Once you have done that, reboot. If you get an infinite shutdown issue (you should given what you describe), wait a few minutes to ensure the OS commited I/O changes, then you can force shutdown. The persistence will work anyway next time, because we already have created the partition.

3. Now reboot again into your USB drive but this time select Kali Linux with Persistence. Once you have booted, try to shutdown. You should see the Kali logo, hit the F12 key to reveal what commands are executed in the background. If at some point you get a very slow sequence where it's written something like: `systemd-shutdown: waiting for gst-plugin-scan` , then do step 4 to fix your issue. If it's another thing that slows down your shutdown, at least now you have something to debug further.
4. If your issue is `gst-plugin-scan` being in an infinite loop, then it's a long known issue since [half](https://gstreamer-bugs.narkive.com/BvRPS7z0/bug-615357-new-gst-plugins-scanner-gets-stuck-in-a-loop) [a](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1837415) [decade](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242540) or so with GStreamer that curses every now and then various Linux distributions with no clear reason. There are various fixes if you want to try, but to me it was not worth it, as it can be replaced by `vlc` since it's just used to play multimedia files, so I simply uninstalled it using: `sudo apt remove gstreamer*` (note that I tried to remove only plugins but it did not work). Now try to shutdown, it should work fine right away! If you booted in Kali with persistence, you won't need to redo this fix all the time. If you don't have persistence, you need to do it each time you boot into Kali.

Enjoy your fast Kali shutdown!

### Original answer

Try a previous/next release, as sometimes there are hardware incompatibilities randomly appearing in some releases (often due to dependencies having some problems). I had the same issue as you but with 2023.3, and when I tried 2023.2 it worked flawlessly (Kali should shutdown literally after a second! Very fast!). For you, it may be worth trying either 2023.3, or the weekly unstable release, all releases are available at: https://cdimage.kali.org/

If this does not solve your issue, you can try to hit the F12 key during shutdown to show what commands are being executed in the background and what is getting stuck. For me, it was gst-plugin-scan. As a workaround, you may next time try to uninstall the problematic service or program (after yo have setup persistence as indicated on the Kali website - do not usn Rufus persistence, it won't work!).

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem too, I have yet to solve the issue but for USB2.0 slow boot, you need to understand the labels "2.0" and "3.0" is not just any label. In short, you can take it as the speed capability of the pen drive. Hence, naturally your 2.0usb will take longer to boot. For the persistence storage at first I have the same problem but I managed to fix the issue by refering to the official kali linux page that require the users to manually setup the sdb stuffs. Hope this help, and lets hope the solution for the main problem can be found one day. Do take note, some cases the sdb setup is not a must if you are not encountering the persistence storage not working problem.

[https://www.usr.com/education/usb3-peripherals/#:~:text=First%20the%20transfer%20rates%3A%20USB,and%20USB%20ports%20and%20cables](https://www.usr.com/education/usb3-peripherals/#:%7E:text=First%20the%20transfer%20rates%3A%20USB,and%20USB%20ports%20and%20cables).

https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/